# Can one of the Shift, Ctrl, Alt or Win keys be used in other purpose like, to type text?

Tags: java, windows, operating-system, keyboard-layout

I want to modify the use of the one of the Shift, Ctrl, Alt or Win keys. For example, if I just hit (not hold it and press another key) the right shift key, it should do something like displaying a special character in a text box. Could some one let me know if this is possible using any programming language like Java?